# Python_Huobi API account type, what is this argument?

Tags: python, api, github, cryptocurrency

The cryptocurrency exchange api of huobi: https://github.com/huobiapi/huobi_Python
Asks for an `Account type` you see it mostly with `Accounttype.spot()`

I have no clue what this means its no where in the documentation or on the internet does any of you know maybe have a clue? I need it to place an order

Answer (score 0):

You can get the account type by `SubscriptionClient`. Based on my trials, there are two main types, namely, `spot` and `point`

`spot` account is referred to all kind of available cryptocurrency provided by Huobi, whereas, `point` account represents Huobi's own point - `hbpoint` which be exchanged into USD or vice versa. Please also find my answer in another post.
["Account" object has no atribute get Huobi_python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795545/account-object-has-no-atribute-get-huobi-python-api)

The original source of the below code is

https://github.com/HuobiRDCenter/huobi_Python/blob/master/example/websocket/reqsignaccountlist.py

```
from huobi import SubscriptionClient
from huobi.constant.test import *
from huobi.model import *

sub_client = SubscriptionClient(api_key="",
                                secret_key="")

def Accountinfo(account_event: 'AccountEvent'):
        global acc
        for account in account_event.account_list:
            if account.balances:  
                account.id
                account.account_type
                account.account_state
                if account.account_type == 'spot':
                        acc = str(account.account_type)
                        print("Account type is: " + str(acc))

sub_client.request_account_balance_event(Accountinfo)
```

Remark: Setting `global acc` in the function of `Accountinfo` is to make local variable -  `acc` into global variable. Therefore, `acc` can be used in boolean operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find account `type` on this Huobi API official document
https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en/#get-all-accounts-of-the-current-user

By calling API https://api.huobi.pro/v1/account/accounts, you can get all your account and their types.

As document stated, the type values are: `spot`, `margin`, `otc`, `point`, `super-margin`

Note that you may not have all above accounts, unless you have activate them.